# Android/Java. Как отследить событие уничтожения Activity в стеке фоновых приложений?

Tags: android, activity, activity-life-cycle, backstack

- запускаю `Activity`;
- нажимаю кнопку *Home*;
- `Activity` сворачивается в стек фоновых приложений:

[image: Стек фоновых приложений]

Если теперь как бы смахнуть влево/вправо, то `Activity` закрывается, но событие `OnDestroy()` не срабатывает.

Вопрос: как отследить это событие?

Как при этом вызвать `OnDestroy()`? Или какой-то другой метод есть (срабатывающий)?

Comment: Скорее всего, вашу проблему можно решить более простым путем. Напишите, что вы хотите сделать, а не *как* вы этого хотите добиться.

Comment: я хочу сделать так: Когда пользователь нажал кнопку Home а потом смахнул влево/вправо мое приложение из стэка фоновых .. то отследить этот момент и завершить корректно как методом OnDestoy() выход и очистку ресурсов сделать..

Comment: Очистка ресурсов в этом случае не потребуется.

Comment: А если нужно в этот момент к базе обратиться на сервер? что-нить.. connection правильно закрыть.., сохранить например время выхода пользователя.. то как тогда?

Answer (score 6):

При таком сценарии использования ничто не гарантирует вызов `onDestroy()`. Если Вам необходимо выполнить какие-либо действия при сворачивании программы, пользуйтесь `onPause()` или `onStop` (в зависимости от того что необходимо).

`onDestroy()` вызывается при правильном закрытии программы. Вот когда Вы нажимаете кнопку "Назад" на телефоне и приложение "сворачивается", то оно не сворачивается, а закрывается и `onDestroy()` будет вызван.

Comment: Стоит лишь добавить, что в **некоторых** случаях onDestroy() вызывается при "правильном закрытии" и со стороны системы, когда та проводит чистку ресурсов.

Comment: Мне НЕнужны события OnPause и Stop т.к. после них Активити все еще находится в списке фоновых задач и оно не разрушено и может быть восстановлено.. А вот Когда пользователь смахнул влево/вправо приложение из списка фоновых, тогда приложение убивается.. Но! OnDestoy() Не срабатывает.. И значит нужно как то отследить этот момент и завершить корректно как методом OnDestoy() - выход, и очистку кэша и ресурсов сделать..